# What is the composition of the manufacturer block of a Mifare Classic?

Tags: data-structures, rfid, mifare

What information is contained within the manufacturer block of a Mifare Classic? From what I can gather:

- Bytes 0 through 4 contain the UID
- Byte 5 contains the BCC for the UID

What about the rest of the data?

Answer (score -1):

The data sheet provides no clue, and also does not distinguish between byte 5 and others (so these may be different in chips by other manufacturers).

I assume, that you mean a sort of checksum, but don't recognize the abbreviation *BCC*.